# How to extract web browser and OS information for Apache access log

Tags: agent

I have configured **Apache** log for give user agent info and i am getting following information,

```
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/32.0.1700.76 Safari/537.36
```

It mentioned **Mozilla**, **Chrome** and **Safari** as well along with Windows NT OS.

Can some one clarify me how extract specific Browser information and OS info is correct ?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because this is a programming site. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Software Recommendations Stack Exchange](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306).

Answer (score 0):

You can use website stat generator programs, like **[webalizer](http://www.webalizer.org/)** or any other newer one.

You will see same browser stats:

[image]

You need to run webalizer daily.

I hope it helps.

Comment: This is not really an answer to the question being asked which is how to use apache webserver to extract this information.

Comment: this totally on a new direction what OP has asked is more specific to a single user who accessed the site and the logs were generated for the requests along with the browser/user agent info, and what you are suggesting shows the most accessed browser on your site